# Cannot Delete An Image From Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to replace an image in Firebase storage with a new one by first deleting the old and then adding the new. The problem is the deletion. I cannot seem to get it to work. Here is the relevant code:

```
 private void uploadFile(){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        db2 = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(id);
        storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + "."+ getFileExtension(imageuri));

                mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageuri).
                        addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                                while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
                                Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                                db2.update("Image URI",downloadUrl.toString()).addOnSuccessListener(
                                        new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                Toast.makeText(settings_activity
                                                                .this, "DP change added." ,
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            }
                                        }
                                ).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(settings_activity.this, "FIRESTROE ERROR "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                });


                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(settings_activity.this, "FILE STRORAGE "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(settings_activity.this, "DELETION ERROR: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the storage reference I used in the code above:

```
FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_pics/"+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

Comment: are you sure you have to be deleting and then adding ? can't you just update it straight ?

Comment: Well, how do i update folders in firebase storage? So far the new picture is just added to the folder but the old one is still present. I want to delete the older one to save on space.